# Delete an array not working with PDO SQL?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sql-delete

it's been 3 hours that i'm trying to delete a row in mysql based on a id ...
Seems simple right ?

Taking into consideration that the array might contains several value:
$result = Array ( [3] => 4_Couture )

```
Array ( [3] => 4_Couture )
$sql_delete = "DELETE FROM users_resumes WHERE id_training_key = ? ";
$stmt_delete= $pdo->prepare($sql_delete);
foreach($result as $r) {
            $stmt_delete->execute($r);
    }
```

This seems to be right no ?
error : PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

Any, any, any clue is very welcome ! thanks a lot from France !

Comment: What exactly is `$result`? Where do you assign a value? `$result = Array ( [3] => 4_Couture )` is **not** valid PHP code

Comment: Alternative approach to current answer `$stmt_delete->execute(array($r));` or use ternary and `is_array`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `$result` is a one-dimensional array like

```php
$result = [ 3 => '4_Couture' ];
```

That means you're trying to call `$stmt->execute()` with a single string value where it **requires** an array.

I suggest you use `bindParam` instead

```php
$stmt_delete = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM users_resumes WHERE id_training_key = ?");
$stmt_delete->bindParam(1, $r);
foreach ($result as $r) {
  $stmt_delete->execute();
}
```

Comment: Dude, you've juste make it work ! Indeed the array wasn't multidimensional ! This is why my code wasn't corking ! I've learned a huge one tonight thanks to you !